# VBA Date in Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, date, office365

I created project in VBA Office 2016 32bit and now I am trying running this in Office 365 32-bit (WIN10) and of course I had problem with DataPicker (solved) but now during running code I have error "Complie error: Can't find project or liberary".
Problem is this:

```
currentMonth = Month(Date)
```

Do you have idea why "Date" can't show me today's date? In Excel 2016 no problems.

Comment: Try `Date()`. Actual it is defined as a function and so 'should' be called with `()`. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date is not defined here. Is it defined elsewhere?
Seems like Date has been redefined.

This code will work for earlier versions too:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim theDate as Date
  Dim currentMonth As Integer

  theDate = Now()
  currentMonth = Month(theDate)
  Debug.Print currentMonth
End Sub
```

Comment: it Works! Thanks!

Comment: This is not the solution. Your expression will normally work. If `Date` should have been "defined elsewhere", that is what to correct.

Comment: The solution is `Now()`

Comment: In the context of your question `Now()` is just a workaround, not a solution.